# Destroying jQuery Supersized on resize

Tags: jquery, resize, supersized

I'm having a problem with using Supersized in a responsive website. If the window width is lower than 480px, than Supersized should be destroyed. If i resize it again for the window width to be larger than 480px, than Supersized should be reinitialized. I have this code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        var newWindowWidth = $(window).width();
        if(newWindowWidth < 480){
            $("#supersized").remove();
        } else {
            $.supersized({
                slides: [{ image: 'images/bg.jpg', title: ''}]
            });
        }
    });
    $(window).resize(function() {
        var newWindowWidth = $(window).width();
        if(newWindowWidth < 480){
            $("#supersized").remove();
        } else {
            /*var loadSupersizedDiv = jQuery('<div id="supersized"></div>').appendTo(document.body);*/
            $.supersized({
                slides: [{ image: 'images/bg.jpg', title: ''}]
            });
        }
    });
```

I know this isn't perfect, but the problem i'm having right now, is that the supersized div duplicates itself with every pixel on resize. Is there a way around this?

Thanks!

Comment: Depending on your markup, the use of [**jQuery .detach()**](http://api.jquery.com/detach/) might be a better choice when compared to `.remove();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to check if supersized is already loaded and if not then load. Right now it loads on every resize.

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    var newWindowWidth = $(window).width();
    if(newWindowWidth < 480){
        $("#supersized").remove();
    } else if ($("#supersized").length == 0 && newWindowWidth > 480) {
        var loadSupersizedDiv = jQuery('<div id="supersized"></div>').appendTo(document.body);

        $.supersized({
            slides: [{ image: 'kazvan-1.jpg', title: ''}]
        });
    }
});
```

Ok, tested it and basically what it does is just it just checks if #supersized already exists then not create a new one.

Comment: I don't actually. Never used typeof before. It's not working either, could you assist me some more?

Comment: @Mathijs Delva, setup a [**jsFiddle.net**](http://www.jsFiddle.net) of your Supersize issue and provide that in your Question so we can debug it.

Comment: Excellent, thanks rain01! Your edited answer is logical and works perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `$("#supersized").width(x)` or `$("#supersized").css('width', x + 'px')` instead of removing and recreating element.